# Can azure devops handle syntax highlighting for SAS statistical software code?

Tags: azure-devops, sas, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to get azure devops to do syntax highlighting for SAS statistics software code?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. There is a language file made for UltraEdit that may be able to be adapted. There are language files for VSCode as well. Probably also one for NPP but none for DevOps that I know of. Try the VSCode ones. They ar eon the extensions tab.